# What are the general steps of a semi-supervised setting?

Tags: dimensionality-reduction, semi-supervised-learning

Let's consider I have 1000 unlabeled data points. Out of these 1000 points, I manually labeled 200. Now, I am feeling lazy and don't want to label manually the remaining 800 data points.

What would be the next step? I am considering using dimension reduction techniques, such as PCA, to visually assess if the dimension reduction accurately separates the labeled data. If it does, I plan to utilize the reduced dimensions and classify the remaining 800 unlabeled data points using a random classifier, for example, KNN.

Does this align with the concept of semi-supervised learning, or am I missing something? Is it necessary to visually inspect the data points to evaluate the performance of dimension reduction and automated labeling?

[image]

[image]

source of images: https://www.kaggle.com/code/shivamb/semi-supervised-classification-using-autoencoders